# Error while changing data type of a column using alter column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, semantic-versioning

I have a table where columns are like this:

```
system_name varchar(255),
from_package_name varchar(255),
from_version varchar(255)
```

The *from_version* column is of *varying characters* type right now which contains the **version** of a certain package. The **versions** should be compatible with this Semantic Versioning [Spec](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) but often times they are not.

So when I am trying to change the data type of this column from **varchar** to [**semver**](https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/) (Semver is a Postgres extension which is a data type for semantic versioning) using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE relations
ALTER COLUMN from_version TYPE SEMVER
USING CAST((COALESCE(from_version,NULL)) AS SEMVER);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  bad semver value '2.16.0-27020175.00aeff62': semver prerelease numbers can't start with 0 

SQL state: XX000
```

which is understandable because not all values in the column are Semver compatible and I want to replace the values that cannot be converted to Semver type with 'NULL' (that's why tried using the COALESCE stmt).

How can I skip the errors and change the data type for all values of the column?

Comment: 1) `COALESCE(from_version,NULL)` is not going to work as `from_version` is not a `NULL`  value so it will the value returned.  For more information see [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL). 2) You will need to clean up the values in the existing form of the table before doing the `ALTER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately semver supplies a function suitable for this purpose, is_semvar.

```
alter table relations alter column from_version type semver using 
   case when is_semver(from_version) then semver(from_version) end
```

But I would think you would want to record and investigate, not just silently discard the broken ones.